# SQL select the longest char

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, maxlength

i have the table customer with column Name varchar(20), adresse varchar(50), tel varchar(10), etc.

how can i select the longest adresse  ?

```
SELECT FROM customer 
WHERE adresse ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select top (1) * from customer order by len(adresse) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a subquery:

```
select * from customer where len (adresse) = (
    select max (len (adresse)) from customer)
```

The inner query figures out the maximum length over all the `adresse` columns, and the outer query gives you all the rows that have that length. And it *may* be more than one.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select max(len(adresse)) from customer
```

Comment: Joe, shouldn't that last one have len and max swapped? What you have is the length of the _last_ address (I think).

Comment: @paxdiablo:No.. Both will give same answer in sql server

Comment: Then that would be a seriously broken implementation though if you can point me to the docs that say that, I'll give you an upvote. In any rational implementation (and I'm pretty certain SQLServer is at least this rational), the `max` of `aaaaa` and `zzz` varchars is `zzz`, whose length is 3, clearly not what you want. What you want is the max of the lengths, not the length of the maxes.

Comment: @paxdiablo: you are absolutely right... that was my mistake...I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT address FROM customer WHERE length(address) = (SELECT max(length(address)) FROM customer)
```

Comment: Please describe your answer in more detail.