# Display highest earning emp's name and salary without using any kind of subquery

Tags: sql, rdbms

Is there really a way to achieve this?  I was asked this question in a recent interview but I forgot to ask the interviewer for the solution when I was given an opportunity to ask questions.

I have tried every possible way to do this but just can't seem to find a way without using a subquery.  I need to display both the name and the salary, not just the salary.

Comment: Don't type in all upper-case; it's considered shouting, and just plain obnoxious to read.

Comment: you are a lucky man, SQL queries can be formed entirely in uppercase....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365953/sql-select-the-longest-char for the principle.

Answer (score 3):

You might order the whole table by salary descending, and fetch only the first row. Doesn't strike me as a very clever interview question, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in MySQL, you can use limit :

```
select *
from employee
order by salaray desc
limit 0,1
```

I don't think there's a way to do it without subquery if limit isn't implemented (like in oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example (assuming salary is not nullable)

```
SELECT a.*
FROM employee a
LEFT JOIN employee b
ON b.salary > a.salary
WHERE b.salary IS NULL;
```